# Does "State Security" have a specific meaning or is it just a generic name?

Tags: meaning, john-le-carre, smileys-people

This sentence was taken from Le Carre's novel *Smiley's People*:

> As a condition of your application being favourably considered by the authorities, you signed an undertaking to the organs of ***State Security*** to perform certain tasks for them during your residence in Paris.

Does *State Security* here mean specifically The Committee for State Security (aka KGB) or is it just a generic name meaning the security force/departments of the Soviet Union authorities? The words are capitalized here, which makes me think it means KGB, but I'm not sure.

Another similar sentence:

> On that date, for insulting organs of ***State Security***, so many more months, extended for bad behaviour, followed by so many years’ internal exile.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

“Organs of state security” broadly refers to the KGB and its predecessor organizations, as well as to military intelligence (the GRU).

It’s been a while since I read the book, but IIRC some of the events being referred to took place before 1954, when the KGB was organized; the “organs” referred to may be the MGB (ministry of state security), MVD (ministry of internal affairs), or even the pre-1946 NKVD (people’s commissariat for internal affairs).

The capitalization is a stylistic flourish of Le Carre’s, similar to the way the narrator of “The Honorable Schoolboy” refers to “a Gold Seam coming from Russia.”

Comment: Apparently KGB is even the Russian abbreviation for "committee for state security". And the East German MfS, "Ministry for State Security" (today better known as Stasi, short for Staatssicherheit = State Security) was created under that name in 1950 (and the MfS features prominently in another Le Carre novel, The Spy Who Came in from the Cold).